# Regarding GET request idenpotency when fetching data in a REST Api

Tags: rest, http, request

In a REST API, GET requests to the same url are supposed to return the same response. I get the use of that for static resources, but if I, for example, GET the user data through a json response, then POST some changes, I would expect that if I do another GET request later, the changes would be reflected.

Eigther I should use another verb (thought I think I am implementing well the idea of GETting) or this style doesnt play well with AJAX. Could be both.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix "idempotent" and "safe" concepts. GET is "safe" as the server should not change any observable state as a consequence of the GET. A client can issue as many GET it wants on the same URL without changing any state on the server. Idempotent means "If the same request is issued multiple times then the server state will always end up the same as if only one request was issued".

That is not the same as saying "The server will always return the same response to a GET", so your basic assumption is wrong: GET can return new results every time. Take for instance a time-of-the-day resource - it would always return a new value for every request.

Comment: Hmm.. I wonder. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCcAE2SCQ6k) from Google Developers emphasized A LOT on caching GET responses, and this only makes sense if it truly responds the same.

Comment: *Some* resources do not change much. These are good candidates for caching. Other resources changes a lot and should not be cached. Figuring out which resources that are cachable - and splitting your data into static, cachable, resources plus volatile uncachable resources is an important part of your resource design.

Comment: Thanks! I really haven't gotten into that aspect. I notice some things get cached by the browser, at this stage it is annoying, maybe I could get the server to respond in a special way so my html is not cached.

Comment: Yes, I would expect the server default behavior to enable caching of HTML files. Search for "http cache headers" to get more general information about caching (this seems like a decent introduction: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching).

Answer (score -1):

Idempotency of GET assumes no other operations. As outlined in http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html it's possible that a sequence of several requests is not idempotent even if all methods executed are idempotent.

So it IS possible for two GET requests to return different data, and as a result we have the concept of ETags that can be used by clients, in combination with precondition type headers like If-Match, to detect if changes have occurred.

Comment: You are citing an obsolete specification. See <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#method.properties> instead.

Comment: Since you're one of the authors of the proposal you referenced perhaps you can explain, apart from the reference to the older RFC, how what I stated is incorrect? Idempotency for a "safe" method MUST assume no changes in underlying data unless the new proposal suggests all resources should include versions in their names to guarantee idempotency?

Comment: My comment was just about using an obsolete reference, not the actual contents of your reply.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for your perspective, but I admit the comment section on SO is probably not the place for that :). Thanks for the pointer to the proposal though!

Comment: It is not a "proposal" but the new specification.